# Update 'MaxConcurrentActivityFunctions' for a durable task once it's published

Tags: azure-durable-functions, azure-function-app

I have a function app with a durable task running on Azure. What is the best way of changing the 'MaxConcurrentActivityFunctions' binding (i.e. in host.json) once it's been deployed/published?

"extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "MaxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 4, // ensures scale-out for mappers
    }
  }

I want to change it to 1 or 4 depending on the type of service plan I use.

I haven't been able to find a way to do it with the Azure SDK, or with a rest api. The only way I can think of getting it to work is to stop the function app, download the host.json file, modify it, upload it, and restart the function app.

Seems like overkill to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

host.json uses the [aspnet core config system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). 
You can set an app setting (environment variable) `AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__durableTask__MaxConcurrentActivityFunctions=1` through the portal (or Azure ARM REST APIs) and it should take precedence over the value in host.json